# Returning offsetWidth of element in percentage or with decimal places to make the width of an overlaying div the same - React / Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Lately I am fiddling a bit in React and I have encountered the following problem, which is not necessarily React related but more Javascript / CSS in general related.

I have created a bar which contains a certain amount of cells. These cells all have the same `width` and `height` properties but will adjust its width/height properties to the `viewport`.

When I click one of these cells a `div` get's appended to the container of the cells, this div is an overlay with a different color (so you know which cell has been clicked).

The problem is that the bar and it's containing cells have their width attribute set in percentage, this has been done so I can calculate the width needed based on the total cell count when adding more cells to the containing div.

The `overlay div` however, which is added when a cell is being clicked, has it's width defined in `px`. This is because the `left` and `top` position of the overlay div is being determined with the `pageY` and `pageX` coordinates and the `height` and `width` of the cell element is being fetched with `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth`.

The result of the above is that the actual width of the cell is a `decimal value` (it is percentage) but the calculated width is a rounded `px` value, this results in the following:

**The normal Cell width:**

[image]

The Overlay div width:
[image]

as you can see this is a minor difference in width, to show it properly I had to zoom in quite a bit. In the second picture you see that how further in `left position` the overlay div is being added, the bigger the difference (which is logical).

**The code:**
This is the normal Cell which is being rendered

```
_onRenderCell = (item, index) => {

this.myCell = React.createRef();

return (
  <div
    className="ms-ListGridExample-tile"
    data-is-focusable={false}
    style={{
      width: 100 / this._columnCount + '%',
      height: this._rowHeight * 1.5,
      float: 'left'
    }}
  >

  ... rest of the rendering omitted ...
```

You can see here that the width is determined based on the column count and returned as a percentage:  `width: 100 / this._columnCount + '%'`

**The onMouseDown event to add the overlay div:**

```
_onMouseDown (e){

    const containerNode = this.rsvnRef.current;
    const cellNode = this.myCell.current;

    // Determine current position 
    let posY = e.pageY - containerNode.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let posX = e.pageX - containerNode.getBoundingClientRect().left;

    // Determine width and height of cell
    let height = cellNode.offsetHeight;
    let width = cellNode.offsetWidth;

    // Determine top and left positions
    let top = posY - (posY % height);
    let left = posX - (posX % width);


    var reservationClasses = document.getElementsByClassName('reservation');

    var collisions = Array.prototype.filter.call(reservationClasses, function(rsv) {
        return rsv.offsetTop == top && rsv.offsetLeft == left;
    });

    if (collisions.length == 0){

        // Creating the overlay div
        const newRsvn = document.createElement("div");
        newRsvn.className = "reservation reservation-creating";
        newRsvn.style.top = top + 'px';
        newRsvn.style.left = left + 'px';
        newRsvn.style.height = height + 'px';
        newRsvn.style.width = width + 'px';

        // Apending overlay div to container
        containerNode.append(newRsvn);

    }

}
```

My question is (as you probably expected); how can I make the overlaying div have the exact same width as the cell div? Can you return the `offsetWidth` with decimal places, or can I in some way calculate the `offsetWidth` in percentage?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, and thanks to this post: [Converting width from percentage to pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358162/converting-width-from-percentage-to-pixels) I managed to get it done.

However, I don't know if it is the best / right solution so please do give feedback if you think there is a better way!

I decided to just set the `width` of the cell in `pixels` instead of a `percentage`. The rendering of a cell is being done dynamically anyway (each time the screen size changes) so calculating the right amount of pixels in the `cell rendering` and rounding that to a whole number works fine since now both the `cell` and `overlaying div` are using the same width.

**The code:**

```
_onRenderCell = (item, index) => {

    this.myCell = React.createRef();
    const containerNode = this.rsvnRef.current;

    let percents = parseInt(100 / this._columnCount);
    let parentWidth = parseInt(containerNode.offsetWidth);
    let pixels = parseInt(parentWidth*(percents/100));

    return (
      <div
        className="ms-ListGridExample-tile"
        data-is-focusable={false}
        style={{
          // width: 100 / this._columnCount + '%',
          width: pixels + 'px',
          height: this._rowHeight * 1.5,
          float: 'left'
        }}
      >

      ... rest of the rendering omitted ...
```